# Click event is not firing for element which changes position when has focus

Tags: javascript, events

When an element has `onFocus` event handler, which changes the element's position, the `onClick` event handler is not firing. This is probably because the click event is actually the combination of `mousedown` and `mouseup` events. So first `mousedown` fires, then element gets focus and the handler changes the element's position. Then `mouseup` fires, but cursor is on some different element at that moment and the click handler is not invoked.

Here is the example:

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var button = document.getElementById('button');
container.style.position = "absolute";
container.style.marginTop = "40px";
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert('Clicked');
}, false);
button.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  container.style.top = (container.getBoundingClientRect().top - 10) + 'px';
  this.blur();
}, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>ClickFocusIssue</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <button id="button">Button</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Particularly, I have a scrollable table with custom scroll. I need it to scroll up and down, when rows in the table receive focus, e.g. with <kbd>Tab</kbd> button. But I need to handle clicks, too.

Is there a good way to handle both events simultaneously?

Comment: Click will give focus, so why not handle it all in the focus event?

Comment: have you tried bootstrap accordion .. ?  https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp

Comment: @Kramb, because click handler do something more, I don't need it, when just receiving the focus.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the mousedown event instead of click. It will fire before the focus event.

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var button = document.getElementById('button');
container.style.position = "absolute";
container.style.marginTop = "40px";
button.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  alert('Clicked');
}, false);
button.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  container.style.top = (container.getBoundingClientRect().top - 10) + 'px';
  this.blur();
}, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>ClickFocusIssue</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <button id="button">Button</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```